# AngularJs - Pass data from associated classes and collections

Tags: class, collections, angularjs

**My Meal Class (server-side)**

public class Meal
{

```
public Meal()
{
    Fruits = new List<Fruit>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Fk_VendorId")]
public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
public int Fk_VendorId { get; set; }

//collection
public virtual ICollection<Fruit> Fruits  { get; set; }
```

}

**Form Html:**

```
 <div ng-controller="MealCtrl>
 <select ng-model="meal.Id" ng-options="meal.Id as meal.Name for meal in Meals"></select>
 </div>

 <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl>
 <select ng-model="???" ng-options="fruit.Id as fruit.Name for fruit in fruits"></select>
 </div>

 <div ng-controller="VendorCtrl>
 <select ng-model="???" ng-options="vendor.Id as vendor.Name for vendor in vendors"></select>
 </div>
```

**Question:**

How to pass the selected associated class  [Vendor] and associated collection [Fruits] to the Meal class on submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the closing MealCtrl div to the end and add meal.FK_VendorId as the ng-model for vendor.

```
<div ng-controller="MealCtrl>
 <select ng-model="meal.Id" ng-options="meal.Id as meal.Name for meal in Meals"></select>

<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl>
<select ng-model="???" ng-options="fruit.Id as fruit.Name for fruit in fruits"></select>
</div>

<div ng-controller="VendorCtrl>
<select ng-model="meal.Fk_VendorId" ng-options="vendor.Id as vendor.Name for vendor in vendors"></select>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: what about the fruit collection?